# With MovableType, how do I make my banner image clickable?

Tags: javascript, moveabletype

I have been having trouble getting my banner image on my blog to be clickable.  If my site has an image named "banner.jpg",  is it possible to make a generic javascript function that makes all images with that particular name on the page be clickable with a hard coded link?

I would like to be able to drop in a short code snippet into the "head" tag section and not have any requirement to edit a style sheet or a movable type template, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need Javascript at all.  Just edit the template for the page in question.  In my MovableType blog, index.html has a div called "banner".  Find the element you want clickable there and wrap in in an anchor (A element) with the URL you want.

Comment: I got it but the reason it was so hard was that the templated I needed to edit was not the index.html template.  I had to edit the Entry template.